Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch
I'm getting a Google OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch error. I receive this error when I add https://domain-name.com and https://domain-name.com/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/, but I can log in with Google when I run these URLs locally (http://127.0.0.1:8000 and http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/). Is there a mistake I might be missing? (Note: I'm using the Python Django library)
Btw:
Verification Status
Verification in progress
The Trust and Safety team has received your form. They will reach out to you via your contact email if needed. The review process can take up to 4-6 weeks. Expect the first email from our Trust and Safety team within 3-5 days. Your last approved consent screen is still in use

I've tried to resolve the issue by ensuring that the redirect URIs specified in the Google Developer Console match those used in my Django application settings. I've also verified that the URIs are correct for both the production server and the local development environment. Additionally, I've double-checked the client ID and client secret provided to ensure they are accurate. Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the redirect_uri_mismatch error. I expected that configuring the redirect URIs correctly would resolve the issue, but it persists.

The client library sends the redirect uri your app is running from if it's running from localhost that's what it sends to Google.  If you code is configure to run from domain name it's domain name
